# Angular 2 - why do we need to use ngForm if we use custom validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, angular2-forms

Hello to everyone who using Angular, and the last Angular2.

I'm working with the forms right now and I see that I'm using custom validation (for example: [native email validation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.emailaddress) doesn't support non-latin symbols, or we need phone validation, or something else) and `[(ngModel)]` instead of `ngControl` and `Validators`.

So why do we need to use `ngForm` with `FormBuilder`, if we can just define `Object` in the constructor?

Simple example:

`ngForm`:

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FORM_DIRECTIVES, AbstractControl, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'form',
  template: `<form [ngFormModel]="ourForm" (ngSubmit)="doSubmit()">
      <input ngControl="ourinput" placeholder="Our input" type="text">
      <span class="error-message" [class.hidden]="!error">{{message}}</span>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>`,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class someFormCmp {
  ourForm: ControlGroup;
  error: boolean;
  message: string;

  constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    let some = this;

    some.ourForm = fb.group({
      ourinput: ['Something...', Validators.required]
    });
    some.error = false;
    some.message = '';
  }

  doSubmit() {
    let some = this;

    // our custom validation
    if (!valid(some.ourForm.controls['ourinput'].value)) {
      some.error = true;
      some.message = 'Field is not valid';
    }

    if (!error) {
      // some tasks what we'll do next
    }
  }
}
```

VS

`ngModel`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form',
  template: `<form (ngSubmit)="doSubmit()">
      <input [(ngModel)]="ourinput" placeholder="Our input" type="text">
      <span class="error-message" [class.hidden]="!error">{{message}}</span>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>`
})

export class someFormCmp {
  ourForm: any;
  error: boolean;
  message: string;

  constructor() {
    let some = this;

    some.ourForm = {
      ourinput: 'Something'
    };
    some.error = false;
    some.message = '';
  }

  doSubmit() {
    let some = this;

    // our custom validation
    if (!valid(some.ourForm.ourinput)) {
      some.error = true;
      some.message = 'Field is not valid';
    }

    if (!error) {
      // some tasks what we'll do next
    }
  }
}
```

There is no big difference if there are one, two, three fields. But if there are 6, 10, or more fields and we are using custom validation, then it is hard to maintain this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit confused, as it assumes `ngModel` opposes `ngForm` which isn't true (as of Angular 4.1.3 anyway).  The two ways of form validation in Angular is "template-driven" (old `ngModel` way) and "model-driven" (new, reactive `FormBuilder` way).

"Template-driven" uses ngModel but not FormBuilder.  "Model-driven" uses FormBuilder but not ngModel (counter-intuitively).  Both use ngForm because both use the HTML tag `<form>`.

The only explicit mention of `ngForm` when using either is usually found in the template-driven way, where `#myForm="ngForm"` appears on the HTML's `<form>` tag.

In the model-driven way, you usually won't see that, and instead see `[formGroup]="myFormGroup"` on the `<form>` tag.  But ngForm is still there even though you don't have an explicit reference to it.

You *can* use `#myForm='ngForm'` in the model-driven world, primarily so the HTML can use `myForm.submitted` for deciding when to display validation errors. In which case the tag will have both: `<form #myForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="go()">`

Comment: yes, when we use `<form>` tag then we don't need to use `ngModel` at all. because it could confuse our app's logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom validator, you need to register it

```
some.ourForm = fb.group({
  ourinput: ['Something...', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required, myCustomValidator
  ])]
});
```

The `myCustomValidator` will look like the following:

```
myCustomValidator(control:Control) {
  if (isValid(control)) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return {
      someValidation: true
    }
  }
}
```

This way the `ourinput` control will handle state of the input by itself internally. You don't need to call it explicitly in your code...

You can have access to the validity of the input using the `valid` property:

```
var isValid = some.ourForm.controls.outinput.valid;
```

Comment: Yes, we can use some our `customFilter`, but when we check form data, for example **international phone number**: `is it empty` (we need to show to user `"empty field error message"`, then if `is it valid by length` (without clearing what user already typed) with error `"your phone almost correct, check its length please"`, `is it valid by format` and so on. I mean when we have many errors messages on the fields. How can we check all of them? And write less code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is useful to you.

ngForm, is one of the main thing to set validation format.

```
<form [ngFormModel]="samform" #f="ngForm">

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="formHeading">User Name *</div>
    <input type="text" ngControl="email" [(ngModel)]="Username" />

    <div *ngIf="email.touched && email.value==''" class="cmsg">
        <p *ngIf="email.errors.required">User Name is required.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
<button (click)="submitData()" [disabled]="!f.form.valid"
    class="btn btn-primary">Sumbit data</button>
</form>
```